# Angular 2 - Unable to copy values from one object to another using typescript for

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a employee object and i want to copy some of the values in to a new object. I'm using Typescript for to copy them, but i'm getting error.

Typescript code:

```
employee = [
    { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
    { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
  ];
  companies : any;
  for (let c of this.employee) {
      this.companies.push({
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      })
    };
  console.log("Companies",this.companies);
```

Plunker code link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/CnBR4JouNhzH3DWm7QCo?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that code in a function. Here I'm running it in the constructor. You can only declare variables in the class.

also you need to initialize `companies` with an empty array.

```
  employee = [
    { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
    { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
  ];
  companies : any = [];


  constructor(){
    for (let c of this.employee) {
      this.companies.push({
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      })
    };
   console.log("Companies",this.companies);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues,

you have to write code iside some function

```
constructor(){
    for (let c of this.employee) {
      this.companies.push({
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      })
    };
  console.log("Companies",this.companies);
 }
```

and initialize companies property,

Check out updated the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/CYbS7YBMNIC9PmY4C8KS?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public employee: any[] = [];
public companies: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = [
    { "empId": "59C", "empDesc": "Software","location":"Dallas"},
    { "empId": "AMI", "empDesc": "Hardware", "location":"San Francisco"}
    ];


    for (let c of this.employee) {
      let temp = [{
        empDesc: c.empDesc,
        empId: c.empId
      }]
      this.companies.push(temp);
    };
    console.log("Companies",this.companies);
}
```